# My Wifi does not work for SSH login or saving some forms

Tags: wireless, network-manager

The system works perfectly fine with wired connection. It has problems accessing wifi at my office. However my wifi at my home seems to work fine.

I have installed wicd and tried many alternatives but somehow it does not help.

Pasted below is dump from lshw for wireless.

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 94:db:c9:49:63:68
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.12.0-7-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your router and turn off AP Isolation.

If it is already disabled try Enabling AP and save the settings, then disable AP and saving the settings again

I had the same problem once.

Comment: It was disabled. I enabled and then disabled Wireless Isolation in netgear router settings. I am able to access ssh now. However, sporadic access to remote ssh used to happen earlier in this wireless connection at times but mostly I was not able to. I will keep a watch and let you know tomorrow if access gets seamless. Thanks :)

Comment: I am still facing issues with connectivity even after switching off wireless isolation.